# Send two arrays with AJAX to PHP, cant get response

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I make two arrays each containing all the needed IDs:

```
$('.valider').click(function(){
        var confirmList = [];
        var refuserList = [];
        var id;

        /* CREATE refuserList ARRAY */
        $('input[type=checkbox][class=refuser]:checked').each(function () { 
          id = $(this).parent().parent().children('td:first-child').text();              
          refuserList.push(id);
        });

        /* CREATE confirmList ARRAY */
        $('input[type=checkbox][class=confirm]:checked').each(function () { 
          id = $(this).parent().parent().children('td:first-child').text();
           confirmList.push(id);

        });

        alert(confirmList);
        alert(refuserList);

        /* check if one of them has at least one element */
        if( confirmList.length > 0 || refuserList.length > 0){
          /* send info to php */
          $.post( "confirm_points.php", { 'confirmList[]' : confirmList , "refuserList[]" : refuserList } )
                    .done(function(data){

                      alert(data);
                      $('.test').html(data);
                    });
        }
      });
```

I try to send confirmList and refuserList to PHP, which seems to work but once I'm in PHP:

```
$accepter =json_decode($_POST['confirmList']);
$refuser = json_decode($_POST['refuserList']);

    var_dump($accepter);
    var_dump($refuser);

    echo $accepter; 
    echo $refuser;
```

It returns this error:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\JAUGE\confirm_points.php on line 5

What do i have to use to reach the arrays in PHP?

**EDIT**

The problem is solved thanks to first comment. 
In the beginning I didn't put the [] in the AJAX request:

```
 $.post( "confirm_points.php", { 'confirmList[]' : confirmList , "refuserList[]" : refuserList } )
                    .done(function(data){
```

So i tried to json_parse, json_decode, but it never seemed to work. When i finally put the [] i was still trying all the json_decode stuff, but it works perfectly without it so final PHP is simply:

```
if(isset($_POST['confirmList'])){
        $accepter =$_POST['confirmList'];
    }
if(isset($_POST['refuserList'])){
        $refuser = $_POST['refuserList'];
    }


    var_dump($_POST['confirmList']);

    echo $accepter[0];
```

Comment: please share the result of: var_dump($_POST['confirmList']);

Comment: Oh, it sends me back the array ! Oh well. Thanks hahaha. It works perfectly

Comment: seriously? What exactly was the question again?

Comment: i explained my error in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST['confirmList']
```

Its array in itself. Dont need to json_decode() this.